# Python Requests declined: "Due to the presence of characters known to be used in Cross Site Scripting attacks, access is forbidden."

Tags: python, python-requests

Dear fellow `requests` users,

**Update:**

Sorry, guys. My error came from a mistake:

My goal was to do this:

```
r = requests.get('http://www.spdrs.com/product/fund.seam?ticker=SPY', stream=True, headers=hdr)
```

I did this:

```
r = requests.get('http://www.spdrs.com/product/fund.seam?ticker={}'.format(['SPY']), stream=True, headers=hdr)
```

Which should be:

```
r = requests.get('http://www.spdrs.com/product/fund.seam?ticker={}'.format('SPY'), stream=True, headers=hdr)
```

The extra brackets **`[]`** were causing the error, apparently. Dumb mistake. Feel free to vote me down, if you wish.

**Original question:**

I am trying to scrape `spdrs.com` webpage using:

```
hdr = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.64 Safari/537.11',
   'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
   'Accept-Charset': 'ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3',
   'Accept-Encoding': 'none',
   'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.8',
   'Connection': 'keep-alive'}    
r = requests.get('http://www.spdrs.com/product/fund.seam?ticker=SPY', stream=True, headers=hdr)
```

But all I get is this:

```
Due to the presence of characters known to be used in Cross Site Scripting attacks, access is forbidden.
```

It's the same with `http` or `https`.

If I remove `hdr`, I get a straight 403 decline.

Is there any modification I can do to the `hdr` to show the website that I am a well-behaving script? I know, servers don't like scrapers.

This [thread on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5249130/due-to-the-presence-of-characters-known-to-be-used-in-cross-site-scripting-attac) shows a similar problem from webmaster's perspective.

Thanks a lot!

Yi

Comment: You could try [contacting the website owner](https://www.spdrs.com/contact/index.seam) and asking them.

Comment: Have you tried removing each header, one at a time, to see which one might be causing the problem?

Comment: I found my mistake, see update. @Robᵩ, I emailed them. Now not necessary. Bryan, thanks for teaching me how to troubleshoot. Appreciate it!

Comment: This underscores the importance of pasting an actual program that you've actually run. Not sort-of like the one you ran, but precisely the one you ran. See [mcve] for more information.

Comment: @Robᵩ, thanks for the pointer. That is really a good guideline! Not only on how to ask question, but also could have systemically prevented/solved my mistake in the process.

Answer (score 0):

Drop the following key/value from your header:

```
'Accept-Charset': 'ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3',
```

It works for me after I did that.

Comment: I found my mistake. See my update. Not `hdr` problem. But thank you all very much for taking your time to answer my question. I really appreciate it.